# Android App force close when using Vibrator instance service not available on create

Tags: android, vibration

Hi and thank you all for the help you have already so nicely given. Let me first say I have never programmed using android! I know a few other languages but I am a beginner at best. I was given this app to change it from beeping to vibration.

thiyagab so nicely gave me the following code:

```
import android.os.Vibrator; ...
```

`Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);`

`// Vibrate for 500 milliseconds`
`v.vibrate(500);`

PS. I slipped in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

However when I compiled it, the app closes and the compiler says that the service is not available before onCreate. So in looking though his code I saw the onCreate heading:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

and moved the

`Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);`

below that line to be included within onCreate. However, now within this line of code (which is further up)

`// Vibrate for 500 milliseconds`

`v.vibrate(500);`

The v variable is in red like it is undeclared. When I hover my mouse over it it says unresolvable. I know this is a silly problem. Can anyone help this newbie? Thank you so much!!!!

*****EDITED*********

Thanks again for your help!!!!

Comment: Please post your whole java class.

Comment: "Clean Project" will fix issues sometimes.

Comment: Here is part of my code in the order it was written. (see above)

Comment: Sorry Raghu, I'm so new I don't know what you are referring to. Link?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to move the `v.vibrate(500);` below the declaration of `v`. But leave them both inside `onCreate()`

If you want to use `v` elsewhere, you will have to declare it first using

```
Vibrator v;
```

Then initialize it inside `onCreate()` using

```
v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

And the use it anywhere inside that Class like this

```
v.vibrate(500);
```

Comment: I actually tried that but it is almost as if v doesn't exist outside of onCreate. Thanks!

Comment: Jonas, Thank you so much! IT WORKED! last step I needed to work on my dissertation! THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 1):

Does this compile?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.vibrate(500);
}
```

Comment: Yes it do! However, as you can see above I use v outside of onCreate. Its like it doesn't exist outside of onCreate. Thanks!